# What type of tree is this?

Tags: terminology, trees, decision-trees

[image]

The checkmarks I've drawn means that the branch ends or a node with the same number allready exists in the tree. I.e it means it reaches some cycle or ends the branching.

I don't know if this is even called a tree? But if so, what kind of specific tree is it? I would like to study this more, but don't know where to find literature on the specifics of this. *(This tree has nodes with actual binary values but I used decimal for better visualization)*.

And also there are two "roots". But some of the nodes could have been connected, like node: 10, but I don't want to clutter the structure too much, or maybe I should redraw the tree-structure altogheter?

***Updated: I've improved the nodes. Now it looks more like a graph. So the question is now is it a digraph and/or what can I derive from this?***

[image]

Comment: A tree is connected. This would be a forest.

Comment: Tree is a connected graph with no cycles, so your picture represents two trees. I do not understand what do you mean by _some of the nodes could have been connected_

Comment: This seems to be a data structure you've invented for some purpose. I doubt that it has appeared before, and that it has a name. Describe it carefully in your paper or computer program and choose an appropriate name.

Comment: Ok @Antoine: I mean that each node has a decision in it, to go left or right. But the route it takes doesn't mean some of the other nodes are connected in a practical sense. Hard to explain.

Comment: @EthanBolker The purpose is that it is invented for studying the Collatz Conjecture. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain where this structure comes from? When are two vertices connected? Which numbers appear at the vertices?

Comment: @Servaes: The structure comes from my research on $(3n+1)/2$ binary-computations. Two vertices are always connected (but a decision is being made if the out-degree of that vertex is $>1$ If the arc has two directions then then $n$ may or may not perform a loop/cycle for a finite number of iterations. I didnt specify in this graph that the ending node is always 0. For a finite number of traversals $n$ will always reach 0. I,e, I call 0 the ending node after some finite time. The graph is fixed, so it never changes any nodes, this is just an example of what paths to traverse.

Comment: The numbers that appear at the vertices are the exact same numbers: $0,1,2....15$. Also there are an infinite number of paths to traverse in the graph itself. But of course $n$ has to be a finite input, so the actual number of paths are finite. I also forgot to mention that if a traversal reach 0, it doesnt have to be the ending of that traversal since it can take other routes, the end of the traversal is only when all of the remaining directions are 0 as well.

Comment: That graph is representing an local Transition Function https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cellular_Automata/Mathematical_Model#Local_transition_function

Comment: I am unable to follow any part of this, except that the vertices are the numbers $0$ through $15$. Are you only concerned with this particular graph, or some collection of graphs on the vertices $0$ through $n$, for all $n$? Also, as any directed edge can be represented as an ordered pair of numbers $(a,b)$, is there a way to determine, given $a$ and $b$, whether the edge $(a,b)$ is in the graph or not?

Comment: @Servaes $n\in\mathbb{N}$ but is always odd in this graph, and is input to $(3n+1)/2$. these vertices are only subsets (I think, If i use the right terminology) to $n$. It's only a local window of the binary expansion to $n$. This graph shows the paths that the subsets of $n$ can take, because we are moving through $n$'s binary expansion like a sliding-window. Not to get too much into the details it use two time-states (but i'll explain that later). Im also interested in a graph that where the function is the denominator of $2^z$ that is $(3n+1)/2^z$ but this is the next step of the project.

Comment: The answer to your last question is yes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand what you have tried to show in your second image, you have
a directed graph (digraph) with a loop and nodes of outdegree two. There may be other structure that you can endow your digraph with if you need it. You don't have a tree because there are directed cycles, for example, $\ 4 \to 10 \to 4. \ $ You can try to find spanning trees of the digraph if you need it. You can try to  use it as the basis for a nondeterministic finite automaton.

Your first image seems to be a labeled multi-rooted tree representing the
[walks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)) from the two root
nodes (12 and 4) in the labeled digraph in your second image. You asked

> So the question is now is it a digraph and/or what can I derive from this?

and the answer is "yes". The multi-rooted tree is one graph object
associated with your digraph.

Comment: I might have been unclear about how the structure works, but you seem to partly answer my question. I don't think I want a tree (or forest) because path-tracing the branches may or may not enter a cycle. So I can't eliminate edges. A more difficult question is wether a path will enter an infinite cycle in Collatz iterations. I think digraph is close to what i need yes, since there are definite directions.

Comment: Updated the thing now, so it looks more like a graph.

Answer (score 0):

I can not fully understand what do the brach ends mean. But if we will ignore them, then we will get a forest, which includes two binary trees. These trees are called binary because each node has two children (and a binary tree is a tree in which each node has at most two children). I don't think you can say anything interesting about the two trees besides the fact that they are binary.

The definitions of tree and forest:

> Tree - an undirected graph in which any two vertices are connected by exactly one path.
>   Another definition: Connected graph without cycles.
>
> Forest - graph without cycles.

(I am sorry for the English, I know it is not perfect)